# Отдельная сериализация ключа и значения в JSON (com.google.code.gson)

Tags: json, kotlin, сериализация, gson

Есть вот такой JSON:

```
{"18797":{"city":"Moscow","street":"Tverskaya","home":"3"},...}
```

И вот такой класс:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

class NewAddress 
{
    @????
    val addr_id = 0

    @SerializedName("city")
    @Expose
    val city:   String = ""

    @SerializedName("street")
    @Expose
    val street: String = ""

    @SerializedName("home")
    @Expose
    val home:   String = ""
}
```

Как я могу десериализовать ключ в общем JSON, чтобы он ложился в addr_id моего класса?

Comment: В данном случае ваш `addr_id` является полем, внутри другого объекта, а адрес значением. Сам json построен неправильно. У вас есть возможность менять структуру json?

Comment: Да, я понимаю. Проблема как раз и заключается в том, что старая структура json используется у меня в старой версии приложения. Поэтому поменять ее будет проблематично

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста отметьте его галочкой с левой стороны

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае ваш `addr_id` является полем, внутри другого объекта. Сам json составлен неправильно, и единственный способ распарсить его это - парсинг в `Map<String, NewAddress>`.

В вашем случае эта часть будет ключём

```
{"18797":{"city":"Moscow","street":"Tverskaya","home":"3"},...}
 ^^^^^^^
```

А эта значением

```
{"18797":{"city":"Moscow","street":"Tverskaya","home":"3"},...}
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Ну да, у меня сейчас так и сделано, просто парсинг такого json выглядит некрасиво в моем проекте. Подумал, что существует более элегантное решение, с учетом отсутствия возможности поменять структуру json